# Spring Eureka Client Failover

Tags: spring, netflix-eureka

I'm trying to get the failover behavior of the Eureka Client working and am receiving the below exception. Eureka server1 is shutdown and I want it to failover to Eureka server2. The application realizes server 1 is down and tries to use the failover, but gets to this place in the code and throws an exception because the backup registry isn't defined.

`2016-07-08T14:25:41.369Z WARN  0 [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: Using default backup registry implementation which does not do anything.
2016-07-08T14:25:41.370Z WARN  0 [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: Cannot fetch applications from apps although backup registry was specified
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Backup registry not implemented.
    at com.netflix.discovery.NotImplementedRegistryImpl.fetchRegistry(NotImplementedRegistryImpl.java:15)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistryFromBackup(DiscoveryClient.java:1811)`

My bootstrap.yml

```
eureka:
  client:  
    fetchRegistry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: https://server1/eureka/,https://server2/eureka/
```

This the line in the Eureka Client the failure is occurring.

```
private void fetchRegistryFromBackup() {
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        BackupRegistry backupRegistryInstance = newBackupRegistryInstance();
        if (null == backupRegistryInstance) { // backward compatibility with the old protected method, in case it is being used.
            backupRegistryInstance = backupRegistryProvider.get();
        }

        if (null != backupRegistryInstance) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following configuration:

```
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    availability-zones:
      us-east-1: us-east-1a,us-east-1b
    region: us-east-1
    service-url:
      us-east-1a: http://<server1>/eureka/
      us-east-1b: http://<server2>/eureka/
```